# Importing Classes & Variables in Python 2.7

Tags: python, file, class, python-2.7, python-import

Hi I'm having trouble importing classes and variables into python files from other python files. Functions work fine.

As a test, I set up file1 with a function, a class, an assigned instance of the class, and a random variable. I then used various methods in file2:

1.
import file1

2.
from file1 import *
error: 'name not defined'

3.
from file1 import variable,class,instance,etc
error: cannot import name Class

4+. And then doing some other things...
creating a **init**.py file

or then trying to set directory:

import os
os.chdir("/Users/mardersteina/Documents")

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Function imports fine, but can't figure this one out with the classes and variables no matter what I'm looking up.

Untitled7:

```
def happy():
    print "yo!"

class Tap(object):
    def __init__(self,level):
        self.level = level

level4 = Tap(4)

x = 14
```

Untitled9:

```
    %run "/Users/mardersteina/Documents/Untitled9.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/mardersteina/Documents/Untitled9.py in <module>()
      1 import Untitled7
      2 
----> 3 print Untitled7.x
      4 """
      5 from Untitled7 import Tap

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x' 



%run "/Users/mardersteina/Documents/Untitled9.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/mardersteina/Documents/Untitled9.py in <module>()
      4 print Untitled7.x
      5 """
----> 6 from Untitled7 import Tap
      7 
      8 print Tap(4).level

ImportError: cannot import name Tap 

%run "/Users/mardersteina/Documents/Untitled9.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/mardersteina/Documents/Untitled9.py in <module>()
     11 from Untitled7 import *
     12 
---> 13 print level4.level

NameError: name 'level4' is not defined
```

Comment: Please show the code which is not working for you. Showing an example of the class in the file1 , and how you try to use it in file2 . Along with any error message you are seeing. It is possible to import classes and variables from other modules (files) , and it works well.

Comment: And in your `untitled7` the indentation is correct? Class/variable `x` is not indented inside the function is it? Try doing `print(Untitled7.__file__)` check if its the same file.

Comment: Indentation is correct. x is not indented. And print(Untitled7.__file__) gives me file location which is the correct file location.

Comment: Also, when you are running the `Untitled9.py` , can it be that you had previously you had imported it in same console when it only had the function?

Answer (score 3):

I can see that you are running the file from an open console .

Most probably the issue is that you had imported the `Untitled7.py` previously when it only had one function . When you do that Python caches the module in `sys.modules` .

So if you try to import it in same session again, you would get the cached version from `sys.modules` , and that would be the reason any changes to the `Untitled7` you did after importing it once are not visible.

To fix this issue, you can `reload` the module -

In Python 3.x , use `importlib.reload()` to reload the module (to take in new changes) , Example -

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(Untitled7)
```

In Python 2.x , use `reload()` method -

```
reload(Untitled7)
```

Or you can also close the python terminal and reopen it, and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you!  I did originally import it with only the function, so this was the answer.

Comment: And Glad I could be helpful.